# Send Json Object to Server (automatically without click/submit button)

Tags: jquery, json

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        //collect userName and password entered by users
        var userName = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        auth(userName, password);
    });
});
```

This is an example of sending json object to my server via click/submit button. I was wondering if there is away to send the data automatically as soon as a page is opened.

My idea is to just get rid of the click function. But is that the right way to go?

Comment: How would you know when the users has completely entered their credentials?

Comment: how does the username and password get entered? If its entered by the user how will you know when they are complete?

Comment: its entered by the user and will be stored as a cookie. THen I will send that info to the server every time they open a page on my website. Then the page will feature their information. THat is why i want to learn how to send the data to the server automatically.

Comment: @user3196499- the click isn't ajax.  it's jquery binding the click event to your anonymous function.  your anonymous function collects the username and password and then calls your auth function.  i'd assume the auth function has an ajax call in it.  be very careful storing a password in a cookie.  you should look into other ways to have the session automatically logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for sending data without submit buttton click

Comment: what would the code look like. I believe the click.function is ajax as well.

Comment: You can call ajax on bodyload function as well  setInterval function

Answer (score 0):

You could always get rid of the button click handler and call the `auth` function when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //collect userName and password entered by users
    var userName = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    auth(userName, password);
});
```

Since this code executes when the page is loaded, it assumes that your server already stored some values in the input fields that you are trying to read. The user won't have any time to type.

Comment: thanks. this should be what i was looking for. I assume I can add a success function which will allow me to return an object and display it on the webpage?

Comment: It depends on what this `auth` function does. Most jQuery AJAX functions already provide `success` callbacks that you could use. So if this `auth` function is using AJAX, you could add it as third parameter a success callback.

Comment: auth function just turns the data into json before sending it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
//    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        //collect userName and password entered by users
        var userName = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        auth(userName, password);
//    });
});
```

Comment: thanks!            And I would still be able to use success function to display objects returning from my server?

Comment: instead of calling the auth function when a button is clicked it will just run when your document is ready/loaded. you can do all of the same things in your ajax call that i'm assuming are within your auth function.